# Yocto dependency cache is not loaded

Tags: caching, yocto, bitbake

When starting bitbake I get the following info that the dependency cache is empty and parsing all recipes takes several minutes. This is very frustrating as with every bitbake command I have to wait 6-7 minutes only for parsing the recipes.

```
Loading cache: 100%                                         | ETA:  --:--:--
Loaded 0 entries from dependency cache. 
Parsing recipes:   1% |#                                    | Time:  0:06:20
```

From time to time the cache gets loaded correctly. So caching seems to work in principal, I just could not find out why it is not loaded most of the time.

I already tried to get rid of .lock files in the build directory, but this also did not solve the problem.

I found out that the bb_cache.dat file that is loaded does not exist. E.g it tries to load bb_cache.dat -> bb_cache.dat.8766c4ab6f5e02381cb595498695990e54b0e58d7e7aed06cfdf517975 which is not existing. Then it parses the recipies and at the end it generates this file that was missing before. Next time when starting bitbake it either loads the previously generated one or (most of the time) looks for a new file and does not find it again. And so on...

Answer (score 0):

Are you changing any of the configuration between bitbake invocations? Are you updating any of the repositories or layers?

It will reparse only when some configuration file has been changed, be that a local.conf file, a bblayers.conf file, or a configuration file in one of the checkouts. "bitbake -D" which enables debug output might give some hints as to why it is reparsing too.

Comment: I use KAS for checkout of repositories and generating local.conf

Comment: When I run "bitbake -D" I get the following output when it tries to load the cache:

DEBUG: Cache: default: Cache dir: /var/yocto/abc/build/tmp/cache/default-glibc/verdin-imx8mp/x86_64
DEBUG: Cache: default: Cache file /var/yocto/abc/build/tmp/cache/default-glibc/verdin-imx8mp/x86_64/bb_cache.dat.898f2f3ba02ed8dcbad79c20db7991ad0352ebda1f472e8d803b1b7994973416 not found, building...
Loaded 0 entries from dependency cache.